# Как передать данные из формы в виде JSON

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Я хочу передать данные с формы в виде JSON. Я знаю самый примитивный способ - объявить кучу переменных и сохранить в них значения формы и конвертировать их в JSON, используя AJAX для передачи

Но есть еще один способ:

```
data: JSON.stringify($("#addClient").serialize()),
```

Как такой массив обрабатывать? Я могу так:

```
print_r($_POST['inputName']);
```

Но для меня это как-то необычно, раньше я делал так:

```
$info = json_decode($_POST['form']);
print_r($info->inputName);
```

И вроде бы понятно.

Возник вопрос: "Это одно и тоже или разные вещи?", то есть я получаю JSON?

Comment: более конкретнее можно сформировать вопрос?

Comment: $info = json_decode($_POST['form']); 
Ты получаешь массив